# Leaflet Layer Control: Ordering

Tags: leaflet

We use the standard ["layer control"](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers) from Leaflet. Instantiation is as follows:

```
this.controls[id] = L.control.layers({}, {}, {
   collapsed: false
});
```

Layers are added dynamically and in random order (depending on when xhr requests complete). However it seems that leaflet implicity uses the _leaflet_id of the respective layer for ordering in the layer control and thus our layers appear in random order.

Is there any way to tell leaflet in which order it should display the layers in the control? E.g. by passing some additional parameter when calling the `.addOverlay` or `.addBaseLayer` methods?

Leaflet version is 1.0-dev

Comment: Is it similar to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20331/how-to-change-leaflet-map-panes-layering-order-z-index ?

Comment: No, the post above is about the order of the layers on the map itself. What iI am talking about is the order in the layer **control**. The thing where you can enable or disable visible layers.

Answer (score 0):

I found some hack-fix for the problem. However this is not a clean solution so feel free to post better answers.

Leaflet uses the _leaflet_id of the layer object for sorting. Thus the layer created first will always be on top. In order to sort the layers you will have to wrap the actual layer in a layer/feature group.

```
|- dummy layer group
   |- some dummy geojson layer
   |- your actual layer (will be added later)
```

Programatically:

```
var oFeatureGroup = L.featureGroup([
    L.geoJson({
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": []
    })
]);
```

Then we do some async loading and once we are ready we add the layer to the - more or less empty - layer group:

```
oFeatureGroup.addLayer(oMyMagicAsyncLoadedLayer)
```

We can then add the layer to the layer control and it will be sorted as "expected" where the order depends on the order of creation of the `oFeatureGroup` layers instead of the `oMyMagicAsyncLoadedLayer`.

Comment: I don't think you need to have a dummy geojson layer - just an empty `FeatureGroup` (or even just a `LayerGroup`) should do the trick.

Comment: You can create an empty featureGroup, obviously, but it won't get a _leaflet_id. Adding a valid geoJSON-Layer (which will have an leaflet_id) will cause leaflet to assign an ID to the featureGroup itself too.

Comment: I'm looking at the Leaflet 0.7.x code for `L.Control.Layers`, and all layers get the `L.Util.stamp()` treatment when they're added. In Leaflet 1.0.0-rc1, internal layer IDs are not used at all, and the layers control uses the order they were added to it.