# Sort order of layers in Leaflet layer control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, geojson

I have created a leaflet map to display some geoJSON data in separate vertical layers.

It works fine, except that the layer control will list the options out of order, i.e. "layer 0, layer 2, layer 1" as opposed to "layer 0, layer 1, layer 2". The data is loaded through AJAX calls, and so the layers are added to the control in the order which the calls complete, i.e. basically random.

According to the documentation for the layer control [ https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#control-layers ], if sortLayers is set to true, the default is to sort the layers by name, but that seems to not be happening.

So, I have tried passing in a sort function explicitly, but the doc does not give an example of what one should look like.

When my code looks like this:

```
var layerControlOptions = {
    hideSingleBase : true,
    autoZIndex : true,
    sortLayers: true}
var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, null, layerControlOptions).addTo(map);
```

The control looks like this:

[layer control with sortLayers: true and no sortFunction being defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjQ05.png)

My best guess at writing my own sorting function:

```
var layerControlOptions = {
    hideSingleBase : true,
autoZIndex : true,
sortLayers: true,
sortFunction: function(layerA, layerB, nameA, nameB){return 
[nameA,nameB].sort();}}
var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, null, 
layerControlOptions).addTo(map);
```

With this, the layer names appear in the same order as when no function is given. Not sure if I am writing it incorrectly, or it is simply equivalent to the default, which is returning the wrong order for some reason.

Seems like the same issue here: [Leaflet Layer Control: Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416404/leaflet-layer-control-ordering/37429612#37429612)

which has no accepted answer and makes no mention of the layer control options. I did try the solution which is proposed here, but it did not fix the problem either.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may look at [this solution](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/f99ef32c5950f246275488c1736dc05c) to order layers in the controls (it does not order layers). I've mainly borrowed code from [Leaflet specs code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/922593addb7ba4a7f5f8a2793d53e03cd04c0b9c/spec/suites/control/Control.LayersSpec.js#L342);

If you have not problem to sort things in the control but you have issue related to loading JSON/GeoJSON (hence layer too) in a particular order, you may want to combine `fetch` with `Promise.all` but it's not anymore about Leaflet but about JavaScript knowledge (look at [this page](https://javascript.info/promise-api#promise-all) to try to grasp `fetch` + `Promise.all`)

Comment: I do not believe I have a problem with loading the data in the correct order. The data ends up labelled correctly as I am loading it, it's just the labels themselves wind up out of order. It does seem now that the label controls are being sorted based on which files are loaded first. I am assuming the point of the sortLayers option is to deal with this. 

In regards to your example, It is helpful to see an example of what sortFunction should look like, so thank you for that, but unfortunately borrowing your function did not work for me.

Comment: Could you provide something like a basic codepen as it seems I missed the point to solve your particular case?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the layers as you normally would and then sort them with a function that removes labels and re-add them as sorted.

```
function sortLabels() {
    var controlLayers = {}
    layerControl._layers.forEach(function(x) {
        if (x.overlay) {
            controlLayers[x.name] = x.layer
        }
    });
    names = Object.keys(controlLayers).sort()
    //remove and add sorted layernames
    names.forEach(x => layerControl.removeLayer(controlLayers[x]))
    names.forEach(x => layerControl.addOverlay(controlLayers[x], x))
}

var baseMaps = { "OpenStreetMap": tile_layer_osm, "ESRI World Imagery" : esri_satelite };

var overlayMaps = {nameC: layerC, nameA: layerA, nameB: layerB}

var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, null, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);
sortLabels()
```